# How to duplicate Xcode Project to create a payment version of a free app

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a free app and I want to make a paid version. I tried to create a new project and copy the class into it but isn't very simple. Is there a way more simple? I duplicate target, but in which way I can set a specified code on a target and another on another target? can you help me?

Comment: Don't duplicate the project, just duplicate the *target* within the project and then make any changes that you need in the new target.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Paul R is right you should not copy the project.. you should create two targets in your app.. because if you fix a bug in your lite version it will automatically fix that in paid version.. in future it will help you a lot..

Here are few articles on how to create multiple targets in your project and how you should work with them -

http://blog.just2us.com/2009/07/tutorial-creating-multiple-targets-for-xcode-iphone-projects/

http://finbarrbrady.com/2010/03/building-for-multiple-targets-in-xcode/

http://www.pacificspirit.com/blog/2009/01/27/building_for_multiple_iphone_targets_in_xcode

Comment: so in xcode 4.2 i have to go to add targets-> empty target true?ù

Comment: No - **duplicate** the target

Comment: In Xcode 4.2, first click on the project which opens another column with the targets listed there. You can right click on that target to duplicate it.