# Can I duplicate an existing Project as a starting point for a different project?

Tags: iphone, xcode

Can I duplicate an existing Project as a starting point for a different project?
I'm also using Git if this matters.

I'd like to not start from scratch since a lot of Project 2 will be the same as Project 1.
So, is there a way to 'copy' Project 1, rename it, and use it for Project 2 (keeping in mind Git)?

BTW I'm using Xcode 4.2

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need to do is go to the first project and then click save as, and save it as project2, then edit it as you would another.

Comment: basically, you use save as to save the same project, then just build on it.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say I am using Xcode 4.2 - there is no "Save As" option.

Comment: If you are trying to create a paid and free version, just create a target of the project....Here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839283/how-to-duplicate-xcode-project-to-create-a-payment-version-of-a-free-app Please mark my answer if it is correct!!!

Comment: Also, you can even duplicate the file by right clicking and saying duplicate (On the file icon) and open it up then change the name....Maybe that could work.

Comment: Sorry, none of the above suggestions worked. I ended up copying the entire project directory and modifying it once I opened it in Xcode. It's not easy, either. You have re-add files to correct the paths, change compiler settings, etc - it's not worth it. I'll build from scratch from now on. Thanks for trying though.